# How do I use the SEARCH function inside the FILTER funtion

Tags: regex, filter, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image: I have a table of information]

I now want to create a filter, that only includes a row of information, if it finds one or more search terms in the associated column.

[image: See image for clarification]

```
=FILTER(A3:C6,(SEARCH(F2,A3:A6)>0)+(SEARCH(G2,B3:B6)>0)+(SEARCH(H2,C3:C6)))
```

Returns a `#N/A` Error.

[Take a Look at the sheet yourself](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xLwn71tUM5IQnGIKhu7ECMoX7tD2wjAv8jgm8rUXhBU/edit?usp=sharing)

This has had me puzzled for an entire day now, and I would love to hear suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=FILTER(A3:C, REGEXMATCH(A3:A, F2)+
              REGEXMATCH(B3:B, G2)+
              REGEXMATCH(C3:C, H2))
```

[image: 0]